# wp-pagenavi keeps loading first page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Hi I had done this correctly but unfornately its still not working, no matter what page I click in the pagination it keeps loading the first page, is it something to do with `$paged`?

```
            <?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
              ?>

            <?php query_posts('cat=14&posts_per_page=3'."&paged=$paged".get_query_var('page')); ?>
            <?php
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $count = 0;
             if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

            .......do stuff


            <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query();?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

oops , answering my own question. I replaced

```
&paged=$paged
```

with

```
&paged=$page
```